# Set producer value for PDFs created by QPrinter

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm currently producing PDFs using python and PyQT.

I'd like to change the "Producer" value of the PDF's document information, currently it is set to "Qt 4.6.2 (C) 2010 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)".

I've looked through the QPrinter reference, and nothing obvious stuck out that I could set.

How do I change the document information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `pdftk` to change the metadata of your PDFs:

```
echo "InfoKey: Producer" > producerinfo
echo "InfoValue: my program" >> producerinfo
pdftk file.pdf update_info producerinfo output newfile.pdf
rm producerinfo
```